# An intelligent species needs same-sex intercourse. Society Effects?

Tags: society, fantasy-races, sex

For one of my Damarian species, the Avari (Felinoid obligate carnivores), they *need* same-sex intercourse of both kinds to increase chances of conceiving.

For females, they can increase their ovulation rates by scissoring with another woman. Males don't have the right dangly bits (Or, more accurately, they have too many dangly bits) to do it right and increase the ovulation rates.

For males, they need anals to increase sperm production (For females, this is impossible, for obvious reasons).

I'm certain this would make their society's view on homosexuality more positive than even the ancient Greeks and Romans (Who were notoriously pro gay, with Roman lesbians being able to get the rights of a man, and a Greek lesbian lending her home island's name to the ENTIRE IDENTITY (Lesbos, BTW), plus her name being an alternate version, and Achilles and Patrolcus were essentially canonically lovers).

However, I don't know if homosexuality being required to increase conceiving rates would change their society beyond their LGBT acceptance.

*Basic facts:*

- All Avari are basically bisexual, with regular heterosexuals being homo only for the fertility increase, and homosexuals only having hetero for reproduction (Avari want women to have many children, and pity childless women, due to their global population being about 5 million, total.
- Avari women are smaller, but noticeably stronger, than men. Avari girls can wrestle down a male 3 years older then them until the males hit puberty. Once the Avari women are 15, they regain their ability to wrestle men 3 years older then they are.
- This results in Avari women ruling their societies. Women lead their government and religious efforts. Males report to females only after a certain point, and males cannot progress beyond that point.
- Most Avari are hunter-gatherers, but some settled and became Bronze Age. This question is about civilization, so the Bronze Age Avari are most relevant.

***Question: What effects would needing homosexual intercourse to boost fertility have on courtship, love, and (Possibly) marriage?***

Note: Magic exists on Damarian, but I don't want it to have a major effect.

Comment: You are fishing for an endless list of just-so stories, aren't you?

Comment: "Effects on society" is always too broad, your entire storyline for this world is going to be based around the effects this has on the society and the differing power dynamics it gives.

Comment: Yep, as other two said. The distance between cause and effect is so large that it capable to fit anything. Any answer will be opinion based or story based or broad fantasy, so vtc for that reason. As inspiration u can look at adorable hyenas, so as monkies

Comment: Being smaller and being stronger aren't usually 2 traits normally seen together in vertebrates, especially since bigger sizes allows for bigger muscles and larger places in the skeleton for these to attach).  If anything in raptors it's normal to see females that are stronger and larger, which we suspect would ensure females would be able to better protect themselves against violent males and dominate them, which is important since males are the main providers while they take care of their chicks. Other theory is that it reduces intersex competition regarding prey.

Comment: Is same-sex intercourse absolutely necessary for the reproduction or it just increases the probability of conception (if it is the latter, how big is this increase)? Are your species promiscuous or not (do they form stable partnerships due to physiological reasons)? What is the family structure? What is their view on marriage (why do people get married)?  How are the marriages arranged (parents arrange them or people are free to choose their partners)? What are the roles of homosexual partners in the family and their relationship to offsprings (are they considered spouses and parents)?